# Full Page JS background colour/images media query

Tags: css, media-queries, fullpage.js

I want to display images as the background for desktop users and for smaller screen users I want to display basic colours as the background for the different sections in full page js. I have so far included only 1 image as a test.

```
#section0{
        background-color: #9aa6a9;

    }
    .section1{
        background-image: url(../imgs/downtown-dubai.png);

    }
    #section2{
        background-color: #9aa6a9;

    }
    #section3{
        background-color: #333;

    }


@media screen (max-width: 750px) {
    /*Section colours for small screens */
    #section0{
        background-color: #9aa6a9;

    }
    .section1{
        background-color: #333;

    }
    #section2{
        background-color: #9aa6a9;

    }
    #section3{
        background-color: #333;

    }
```

Section 1 does not override and the image does not remove for smaller devices. How do I do this?

Comment: just you are using `bootstrap` than you can use `xs-hidden` class to that image if not than you have to do it from javascript

Comment: If you want to remove the background image you need to override the `background-image` property. Currently you are just setting a `background-color`. This won't remove the image. Add `background-image: none;` to your media query

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `background-image` property for mobile too:

```
    #section0{
        background-color: #9aa6a9;

    }
    .section1{
        background-image: url(../imgs/downtown-dubai.png);

    }
    #section2{
        background-color: #9aa6a9;

    }
    #section3{
        background-color: #333;

    }


@media screen (max-width: 750px) {
    /*Section colours for small screens */
    #section0{
        background-color: #9aa6a9;

    }
    .section1{
        background-image: none;
        background-color: #333;

    }
    #section2{
        background-color: #9aa6a9;

    }
    #section3{
        background-color: #333;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated (Y)